# Get data from 2D array in analytical web app

Tags: javascript, d3.js

this is what i get from my console log in chrome developer mode, this is from bi tool.  i am trying to retrieve the data for arcMarkPct so that i am able to create my custom canvas chart on my analytical dashboard in arcadia data

Ive tried many ways to get the data but i am always receiving undefined in my log. when i print the whole array, this is what it returns.

```
 (7) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
    0: Array(2)
    0: "North America"
    1: "4694"
    arcMarkPct: "51%"
    arcTooltipPct: "50.77%"
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
    1: (2) ["Asia ex Japan", "1117", arcMarkPct: "12%", arcTooltipPct: "12.08%"]
    2: (2) ["LATAM excluding Mexico", "567", arcMarkPct: "6%", arcTooltipPct: "6.13%"]
    3: (2) ["EMEA", "1362", arcMarkPct: "15%", arcTooltipPct: "14.73%"]
    4: (2) ["Japan", "80", arcMarkPct: "1%", arcTooltipPct: "0.87%"]
    5: (2) ["Mexico", "1407", arcMarkPct: "15%", arcTooltipPct: "15.22%"]
    6: (2) ["NULL", "18", arcMarkPct: "0%", arcTooltipPct: "0.19%"]
    length: 7
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

For an instant if i were to select

```
var data = rows;
console.log(row[0])
```

This is what my log will reflect, i know theres a length of 2. i am able to get data for country the count, but i am unsure on how can i get the data for arMarkPct & arcTooltipPct. The software does not allow me to look at the code to identify if type its declared .

```
["North America", "4694", arcMarkPct: "51%", arcTooltipPct: "50.77%"]
0: "North America"
1: "4694"
arcMarkPct: "51%"
arcTooltipPct: "50.77%"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I tried row[0][2]  but returns undefined, 
i also tried row[0][2] and some other but all has failed and returns undefined.

Comment: The second element is at index 1, not 2.  So just try `row[0][1]`

Comment: i am trying to retrieve the data from index 2 = which is arcMarkPct.   if i did a length count . it will return 2 . 0 = North america , 1 = 4694 , 2 = arcmak & arctool .

Comment: OK, so `console.log(row[0])` causes the content in the last box to be logged, right?  I'm unsure because you have that `var data = rows;` line before it which is doing nothing related to the logging.  But if `console.log(row[0])` shows that output, then `console.log(row[0].arcMarkPct)` should log just the value you want.

Comment: I have already tried that previously and it returns undefined . `var data = rows;` , rows are getting from bi api, which will printout like what ive posted above.